# how can url masking in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, minimize

my url `www.xyz.com/as/as/as/as`  but .com after all controllers and method hide or minimize to how and use in codeigniter.

how can url masking my url www.abc.com/as/a/s but show only www.abc.com only. how can solve this error in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the default_controller in routes.php to;

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'as/a/s';
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#default